# What should be the correct path of templateUrl in angularJs directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to give path of templateUrl as a seprate .jade file. But its showing **500 err** and **Error: [$compile:tpload]** .

Below is the code in my directive

```
app.directive('personRecord',['$http',function(http){
    return{
        restrict : 'AE',
        templateUrl : '../../views/template.jade',
        link : function(scope,ele,attr){

        }
    }
}]);
```

and my folder structure is like below.

```
bin
node_modules
public
|-- js
    |-- main.js
routes
views
|-- template.jade
|-- index.jade
app.js
package.json
```

Please help me out in this ! What am I missing here !

Comment: It should be relative to your index.html file, I think.

Comment: Hey you are using express ? If yes what is your static folder in it ?

Comment: its public @squiroid

Comment: @Vikash i tried giving '../views/template.jade' and 'template.jade' it doesnot work

Comment: So how can you access views on server ? from client side main.js

Comment: oh yes. guess i got it terribly wrong ! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion for you is to put your views folder inside the public folder:-

```
bin
node_modules
public
|-- js
|    |-- main.js
|--views
    |-- template.jade
    |-- index.jade
routes
app.js
package.json
```

And then use

```
app.directive('personRecord', function(http){
    return {
        restrict : 'AE',
        templateUrl : 'views/template.jade',
        link : function(scope, ele, attr){

        }
    };
});
```

Hope it helps :)